# Binary classification thresholds Keras

Tags: keras, neural-network, classification

wondering if anyone can help explain something I'm struggling with!

I've built as a vanilla network for a binary classification:

```
class DNNClassifier(Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(DNNClassifier, self).__init__()
    self.dense1 = Dense(128, activation='relu',input_shape=(94,))
    self.dense2 = Dense(164, activation='relu')
    self.dense3 = Dense(128, activation='relu')
    self.dense4 = Dense(64, activation='relu')
    self.dense5 = Dense(32, activation='relu')
    self.dense6 = Dense(16, activation='relu')
    self.dense7 = Dense(8, activation='relu')
    self.output1 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
        
        
  def call(self, inputs):
    x = self.dense1(inputs)
    x = self.dense2(x)
    x = self.dense3(x)
    x = self.dense4(x)
    x = self.dense5(x)
    x = self.dense6(x)
    x = self.dense7(x)
    return self.output1(x)
```

It works very well, f1 score at 98! However to get this I have to choose a very odd threshold for assigning the values to each class because the numerical outputs of the final layer are like 3.2346447e-20 or on that scale. Why is this? Why does the sigmoid layer not ensure it's more normalised?

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Well, first of all, I do not know which type of problem are you facing, but I'm sure you don't need that number of hidden layers. USe more hidden layers if your data is "complex" to learn, but don't get too greedy or you may have an overfitted model if you don't have enough train data. Try first with less hiden layers, it might work better.
-Maybe the reason your model has that small outputs is because of the dataset is unbalanced: there are more `0` outputs than `1` or vice versa.

Comment: The data is balanced. I took your advice and reduced the complexity of the network, results still the same unfortunately.